# Display php array item if true

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'new_service' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'service_name' => 'wi-fi',
        'this_service_is_present' => true,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'service_name' => 'Washing machine',
        'this_service_is_present' => false,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I need to display the service if it is present, or ideally show both but say this is is present/not present.

I tried few bits just to test if I was able to grab the values and then work it out, so:

```
$repeater = get_field('servizi_casa');
foreach( $repeater as $row ) {
  echo $row[0][0][1];
}
```

Or

```
$repeater = get_field('servizi_casa');
foreach( $repeater as $row ) {
  echo $row['service_name'];
}
```

And

```
$repeater = get_field('servizi_casa');
foreach( $repeater as $row ) {
  echo $row[0]['service_name'];
}
```

But I'm doing it wrong as I get not values

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde the array in the question is exactly what we get when we do var_dump($repeater); !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your output is the value of `$repeater`, this code should work:

```
foreach ($repeater as $row) {
    foreach ($row['new_service'] as $service) {
        echo "{$service['service_name']} is " . ($service['this_service_is_present'] ? "" : "not ") . "present\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
wi-fi is present 
Washing machine is not present
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QtP6T)

Comment: @rob.m you definitely could get it directly e.g. `$repeater[0]['new_service'][0]['service_name']` but this will give you all results within `$repeater` without having to figure out which indexes are present

Comment: I see, makes sense. Will accept it in a bit, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'new_service' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'service_name' => 'wi-fi',
        'this_service_is_present' => true,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'service_name' => 'Washing machine',
        'this_service_is_present' => false,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


foreach($a[0]['new_service'] as $k) {
   if($k['this_service_is_present'])
     echo $k['service_name'] .'is present';
   } else {
      echo $k['service_name'] .'is Not present';
   }
}
```